# Not able to fetch data from VM if sending password as securestring

Tags: powershell

Below is the code I have to get data from a linux VM.

```
$username = Read-Host "Please enter VM Admin user Name"
$password = Read-Host -assecurestring "Please enter VM Admin password"
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))

$plinkpath = 'C:\Program Files\PuTTY\'
$servername = Read-Host "Please enter targeted linux VM IP Address"
$cmd = 'df -h'
$diskinfo = @(echo y | &($plinkpath + "plink.exe") -pw $password $username@$servername $cmd)
```

If I pass the password like this I am not able to get the output of the command, but when I send password as raw string

```
$password = Read-Host "Please enter VM Admin password"
```

I am able to get the output of the command.

Please let me know what is the reason for this.

Comment: Did you `Import-Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security'`?

Comment: Yes. it is there

Comment: Ok.  I think I misread your question.  You are asking why you don't get output?  Well the reason is `-assecurestring` which should show `*` instead of typed output.  What version of PS do you have? ( For better readability `$password = Read-Host "Please enter VM Admin password" -AsSecureString `)

Comment: Yes. got that. thanks @tukan

Comment: So does it work for you now?

Comment: Yes. worked for me

Comment: Great.  I have converted the comment to answer please accept it and upvote :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `-assecurestring` which should show `*` instead of typed output.

For more see [Read-Host MS manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) .

For better readability:

`$password = Read-Host "Please enter VM Admin password" -AsSecureString`